# Injecting bean inside a custom all repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

Am implementing a custom all Spring Data Jpa repository like

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TenantAwareRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID> {

@Override
Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

and implemented it like

```
@Slf4j
public class TenantAwareRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements UserAwareRepository<T, ID>{

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices defaultTokenServices;

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public TenantAwareRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

        // Keep the EntityManager around to used from the newly introduced methods.
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable){
        OAuth2Authentication authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        log.info("Token = {}", details.getTokenValue());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately `defaultTokenServices` does not get injected and is `null`. How do I inject a spring bean in a custom-all repository implementation.

Comment: What about putting a spring annotation like `@Component` or `@Repository` on `TenantAwareRepositoryImpl`?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to add custom behavior to all repositories:

Ths issue is that `TenantAwareRepositoryImpl` class should `implement` `TenantAwareRepository` like shown below:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TenantAwareRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> 
   extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements TenantAwareRepository<T, ID>{
    //add your code here
}
```

Comment: You answer assumes that am trying to add custom behaviour to a single repository. Well am trying to add custom behavior to all repositories and followed the steps as mentioned in the doc. The custom repository implementation works and am able to set a break point and debug as well. But the problem is that am not able to inject a spring bean inside the custom repository implementation.

Comment: Can you try adding `@Component` as the class level annotation for `TenantAwareRepositoryCustomImpl`?

Comment: @FFL did you solve this issue? can you please let us know how.

Comment: @deependrax I managed to solve it using a combination of a repository advisor(for select queries where I would extract the tenant ID from the security context and apply a hibernate filter) and @PrePersist/@PreUpdate callback methods where I would set the tenant ID from the security context, if it is not set already. Hope that helps.